# Label expression help with loop field and multiple fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, expression

I have 13 fields I need to Label all in one Label.  But I dont want to label values with zero.  Need to have Label before each field example (Field is (C_B) and need to read C&B, 2).  Here is what i have so far but not sure if this is correct.

```
def findlabel ([VF_CL], [C_B], [VF_C_R], [VL_C_R_Unp], [MH_F_C], [MH_F_C_Unp], [Reset_MH_F], [Reset_MH_1], [RtoG], [RtoG_Unpav], [Voids], [Joints],[Drop]):
    # Set up the Headers
    Label = "VF CL " + [VF_CL], "C&B " + [C_B], "VF C/R " + [VF_C_R], + "  (not sure if this is correct)
    # Loop through Fields
    flds = [[VF_CL], [C_B], [VF_C_R], [VL_C_R_Unp], [MH_F_C], [MH_F_C_Unp], [Reset_MH_F], [Reset_MH_1], [RtoG], [RtoG_Unpav], [Voids], [Joints],[Drop]]
    for fld in flds:
        if (fld)>0:
            label =
        else:
            return None
    return Findlabel
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. I haven't figured out how to do it in a loop to simplify it, unfortunately

```
def findlabel ([VF_CL], [C_B], [VF_C_R], [VL_C_R_Unp], [MH_F_C], [MH_F_C_Unp], [Reset_MH_F], [Reset_MH_1], [RtoG], [RtoG_Unpav], [Voids], [Joints],[Drop]):
  if float([VF_CL]) > 0:
    Label = "VF CL, " + [VF_CL] + " "
  if float([C_B]) > 0:
    Label += "C&B, " + [C_B] + " "
  if float([VF_C_R]) > 0:
    Label += "VF C/R, " + [VF_C_R] + " "
  #
  # rest of the fields
  #
  return Label
```

Comment: #def only works when i use if float([VF_VL]) >=0: for the 1st line not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

```
# assuming your final product is string concatenated with all the values formatted like stated
value1 = 1
value2 = 1
flds = [['fieldstr1',value1],['fieldstr2',value2]]
def make_label(flds):
    total_label = ''
    for row in flds:
        if row[1] > 0:
            label = '%s,%s' % (row[0],row[1])
            total_label += label + ' '
    return total_label[:-1]
print make_label(flds)
```

output : 'fieldstr1,1 fieldstr2,1'